# How to get custom post type taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type `portfolio_posts` using the CPT UI plugin. Using the same plugin, I have created a taxonomy `portfolio_category`. I have made multiple entries under this taxonomy.

I want to list all the entries under `portfolio_category`, but all I'm getting is an empty array.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category'
  );
$taxonomy = get_categories ($args);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($taxonomy);
exit;
```

When I replace `portfolio_category` with `category` I am successfully getting all the entries under `category`.

What am I missing here?

[Here is a screenshot of the entries under portfolio_category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYFB5.png) and below is an example of how they are saved in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table.

[image: How they are saved in wp_term_taxonomy table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i did it

```
$taxonomy = get_terms('portfolio_category', array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ));
```

i am able get all the items under portfolio_category.

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'yourtaxonomyhere' ); 

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'yourtaxonomyhere' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;

    echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

}
```

Comment: Answers should be more than a code snippet. Please improve your answer with an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/227902/edit) explaining what your code does and how it answers the question.